# Upgrade to Rails 3.1.1 and Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

Just have upgraded my rails app to Rails 3.1.1 and have get the following error:

```
Routing Error
undefined method `filter_parameter_logging' for ApplicationController:Class
```

application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper :all
  helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user
  filter_parameter_logging :password, :password_confirmation
  ...
```

Do you have any idea about this?
Thanks!

Comment: Seems duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206234/routing-error-when-used-authlogic-with-rails-3-2-9

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in application.rb

```
config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation]
```

and remove `filter_parameter_logging` from application_controller as it is inoperative in Rails 3