# Routing Error when used Authlogic with Rails 3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, runtime-error, authlogic, rails-routing

I have configured authlogic gem for user management needs by referring https://github.com/jonathandean/authlogic_example. I have configured everything correctly. I am using Rails 3.2.9 and ruby 1.8.7. I am getting the following error when I took `localhost:3000`

```
Routing Error

undefined method `filter_parameter_logging' for ApplicationController:Class

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Please help to resolve this. Thanks for any help :)-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the problem resolved.

The answer is, in Rails 3, `filter_parameter_logging` in `ActionController` is deprecated and has no effect, so remove that line and set `‘config.filter_parameters’` in `config/application.rb` instead, like this:

```
config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation]
```

Problem resolved.